# I need to mock a method for a Unit Test in golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I have a function called `NewSchema(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, groupName string, schemaName string, schemaText string)`, that calls a different function called `SubmittingIdentityHasOU(ctx, 'random_string')`. I am writing a Unit test for the NewSchema function.

I have been trying to mock the response of `SubmittingIdentityHasOU` so that it returns true or false depending on the case of my tests. However, it seems that every time I try, the tests doesn't call the mock of said function, but it calls the actual implementation in the main code, which obviously causes a lot of trouble.

I'd like to learn how can you mock the behavior of the embedded functions so that you can easily tests the cases for the NewSchema function.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an interface like SubmittingIdentityHasOUInterface.
You add that interface to as an additional parameter.

Then in test, you send the mock implementation.
Thats it.

Its in detail explained here: https://www.go-on-aws.com/testing-go/interface/interface-mock/